# What's the link?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, pattern

- 2 -> Sudoku
- 30 -> Tic Tac Toe
- 33 -> Rubik's Cube
- 39 -> 2048
- 100 -> Sudoku
- 143 -> Seven Bridges of Königsberg
- 269 -> Magic Hexagon
- 323 -> Rubik's Cube
- 27914 -> The Finger Game
- 49755 -> Russian Roulette
- 74275 -> Snakes and Ladders

### - 31896 -> ?

They're all games, but what's the link? It's puzzling!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

31896 ->

> Othello

because

> these are PSE question numbers, corresponding to questions about particular games, and question 31896 is about Othello.

So indeed

> the link is *Puzzling*.

Comment: Well done! How could I have made it harder? less examples, or left out the comment?

Comment: Double You Oh Double You.

Comment: It might have been a little harder without the comment, or without the [metapuzzles] tag. (Which wasn't strictly _correct_ but was still _informative_!) But I _think_ the correct answer would still have been the first thing I'd have thought of :-). Maybe if there hadn't been any five-digit numbers?

Comment: Can you please write the acronym of that answer in full? Wikipedia has ~30 possibilities....

Comment: If you mean rot13(CFR), it stands for rot13(Chmmyvat Fgnpx Rkpunatr, v.r., jurer jr ner evtug abj).